# How to select columns after inner join

Tags: sql

Once I have joined two dataframes by a specific column I then want to select specific columns from this table - how can I do this?

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    land_birds
INNER JOIN
    sea_birds
ON
    land_birds.colour = sea_birds.colour

SELECT
    colour,
    beak,
    size, 
    weight
FROM
    TABLE
```

However I get the following error:

> near "SELECT": syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a second select, use the first one.

For example, this will get the name and flavor of each land and sea bird pair.

```
SELECT
  land_birds.nane, land_birds.flavor,
  sea_birds.name, sea_birds.flavor
FROM 
    land_birds
INNER JOIN
    sea_birds
ON
    land_birds.colour = sea_birds.colour
```

Note that because you're joining two tables, you will get the columns of both tables in each row.

Comment: That's definitely a better choice! Is there a way to drop one of the columns afterwards? like the column `colour` once it has merged?

Comment: @teslajohn Just don't ask for it in the select. And I do mean "ask"; SQL is declarative. Rather than thinking about a query as merging data, think about it as describing the result you want.

Comment: @teslajohn Perhaps you're thinking `on land_birds.colour = sea_birds.colour` means that only the color columns will be "merged". Instead that tells SQL to match land_birds rows with sea_birds rows which have the same color. Whole rows are joined together regardless of what's in the `on` clause.